# Rails, using Json feed in owl carousel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, owl-carousel, jbuilder

I am trying to implement a responsive carousel using [owl carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/json.html). However, I am struggling to make it work with a json data feed.

Working through what the issue may be, I can say for certain the browser is rendering the getting the feed correctly because I can visit `"http://localhost:3000/api/carousel_items/index.json".` and see the data I want in my carousel.

I think it might be to do with how the json feed is constructed although I can't be sure. Looking at the documentation I can see the [json feed being constructed slightly differently](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/json.html) compared to mine below.

```
[
  {
    "title": "Practical Cotton Hat",
    "url": "http://fahey.org/lane.harris",
    "main": {
      "src": "brands/proraso.png",
      "alt": null
     }
   },
]
```

If this is the case, then how would I construct a json feed that? I am using jbuilder to construct my json feed, but can't seem how to replicate the structure in the owl carousel documentation.

```
json.array! carousel_items do |carousel_item|
  json.title carousel_item.title
  json.url carousel_item.url
  json.partial! "/api/shared/images", img: :main, path: "brands/proraso.png", alt:carousel_item.asset

end
```

Thanks